# Dutch sentiment analysis RobBERT

Tags: python, bert-language-model, roberta-language-model

I have a question about Dutch sentiment analysis in Python. For a project at school I want to analyse the sentiment of a Dutch interview. I have worked with Vader but that doesn't work in Dutch. So I found RobBERT: a Dutch RoBERTa-based language model. When I run this code, with result1 being a positive sentence and result2 a negative sentence, the positive sentence has LABEL_0 with a score of 0.568 and the negative sentence also LABEL_0 with a score of 0.533. Is this output right or am I doing something wrong because the scores do not differ much. Thanks in advance!

```
from transformers import RobertaTokenizer, RobertaForSequenceClassification
from transformers import pipeline
import torch

model_name = "pdelobelle/robbert-v2-dutch-base"
model = RobertaForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(model_name)
tokenizer = RobertaTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)

classifier = pipeline('sentiment-analysis', model=model, tokenizer = tokenizer)

result1 = classifier('Ik vind het mooi')
result2 = classifier('Ik vind het lelijk')
print(result1)
print(result2)
```

Comment: Can you give the translation of the sentences for those of us who don't speak Dutch?

Comment: result1 = I think it is beautiful, 
result2 = I think it is ugly

Comment: That makes sense, then - so they differ by one word, but have exact opposite meanings. That's actually a good test case for sentiment analysis.

Comment: This question is literally where I'm stuck now as well. Did you manage to make it work Niels?

Answer (score 0):

When I used 'DTAI-KULeuven/robbert-v2-dutch-sentiment' instead of 'pdelobelle/robbert-v2-dutch-base' it worked as expected.